# emacs 24: How do I get back emacs-23 sexp behavior for python mode?

Tags: python, emacs, progress

I'm running both emacs 23 and 24 with "--no-init-file" to avoid loading my customizations.  But then I explicitly load my ancient version of python-mode.el (version 3.105, last copyright notice 1998), and see the same behavior I'm about to describe, so I believe it's core emacs, not python.

Consider this code (the `*` marks the cursor location):

```
*def emacs_is_fun():
    for x in range(3):
        print(x)
```

Put the cursor at column 4 at the start of "def".

With emacs 23, running `mark-sexp` selects "def".

With emacs 24, `mark-sexp` selects the entire code block, to the end
of the print statement.

This isn't bad.  The main problem is this common usage:

```
    *very_long_var_name[very_long_expn] += long_function_call(long_arg_list, blah)
```

Again, the cursor is at the start of the printable part of the line, col 4.

In emacs 23, `mark-sexp` selects `very_long_var_name`.

In emacs 24, `mark-sexp` selects the full line, from col 4 to the end.

I've been using `Ctrl-alt-space alt-w` to quickly save variable names.
(Or `alt-2 ctrl-alt-space alt-w` to save a ref expression.) Now it's
gone. It's emacs, so this must be customizable, but I haven't found
where the new behaviour is implemented (and remember I'm using a python-mode
that is about 15 years old). What do I need to put in my .emacs file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Eric Interesting. Thanks for the context in the comment of my other answer.

I think you may just want this then:

`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (setq forward-sexp-function nil)))`

From comments inside `python-mode` built-in emacs 24 (which I think you may be getting instead)

> At last but not least the specialized `python-nav-forward-sexp` allows easy navigation between code blocks.  If you prefer `cc-mode`-like `forward-sexp` movement, setting `forward-sexp-function` to nil is enough...

This gels closer to what I think of a sexp as, like mentioned in my other answer, but outside of lisp a sexp seems at least somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: That's it exactly! Much thanks! This still works as expected for parenthesized expressions and strings. The other problem I have with the new behavior is its asymmetry: sit on a 'def', fwd-sexp goes to the end of the block, but once there (fwd-sexp -1) goes back one traditional sexp.

Comment: No problem. Happy that helped. Not sure I fully understand your second question. If you're still having an issue, then please make a new SO question with an example and @ me in the comments and I'll be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was a bug fix in emacs 24. As that is technically now marking the full sexp. It seems like you want the functionality of marking a symbol instead.

I *think* by putting this in your `.emacs` you'll get the functionality you want.

```
(defun your-mark-symbol (&optional arg allow-extend)
  "mark-sexp in lisp.el but with fowrad-symbol instead of foward-sexp"
  (interactive "P\np")
  (cond ((and allow-extend
          (or (and (eq last-command this-command) (mark t))
          (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)))
     (setq arg (if arg (prefix-numeric-value arg)
             (if (< (mark) (point)) -1 1)))
     (set-mark
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (mark))
        (forward-symbol arg)
        (point))))
    (t
     (push-mark
      (save-excursion
        (forward-symbol (prefix-numeric-value arg))
        (point))
      nil t))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-SPC") 'your-mark-symbol)
```

Note that is literally a copy of `mark-sexp` but with `foward-symbol` instead of `forward-sexp`.

This could very well cause unexpected weirdness if you're using `mark-sexp` via <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd> in other buffers/modes, in which case you would want to do make this keybinding via mode hook instead.

Comment: I think this is a regression introduced in v 24. I've been editing python files in emacs for over 15 years, and this is the first time I ran into this behavior. And I still want sexp matching. In my example I alluded to using `alt-2 ctrl-alt-space alt-w` to yank `very_long_var_name[very_long_expn]`, where the expression could contain multiple words.  There seems to be some other hook going on here, and would like to know how to narrow it down.